# split() on tabs may not split on every tab

Tags: perl

I have a file of one line:

```
 $ od -c testData.txt 
 0000000    6   7   7   7   1   0  \t   0  \t   1  \t   L   P   A   Y  \t
 0000020    F   6   3   5   P   3   B  \t   L   P   A   Y   0   0   0   0
 0000040    1  \t   F   R   M  \t   H   O   U   S   T   O   N       G   R
 0000060    O   U   P       (   a   k   a       C   O   R   P   O   R   A
 0000100    T   E       A   D   V   O   C   A   T   E   S       I   N   C
 0000120    .   )       T   H   E  \t  \t  \t  \t   S   a   c   r   a   m
 0000140    e   n   t   o  \t   C   A  \t   9   5   8   1   4   -   2   8
 0000160    2   5  \t   (   9   1   6   )       4   4   7   -   9   8   8
 0000200    4  \t  \t   6   4   9   9   .   9   8  \t   1   7   .   1   9
 0000220   \t   0  \t  \t   6   5   1   7   .   1   7  \t   3   9   3   0
 0000240    9   .   2   3  \t   N  \t  \t  \t  \r  \n                    
 0000253
```

I have a script which does the one thing:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 $line = <STDIN>;
 @p = split '\t', $line;
 chomp(@p);
 for ($idx = 0; $idx < scalar(@p); $idx++) { print $idx.": \"".$p[$idx]."\"\n"; }
 exit(0);
```

I am on Mac OS X 10.8.5 and using the stock perl (perl 5, version 12, subversion 4 (v5.12.4) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level).

If I do not pipe the data through col then I see a glitch from the line-ending. If I do then the split() function will ignore a few tabs. Not all, just a few. Really. Annoying.

```
 $ ./testSplit < testData.txt 
 0: "677710"
 1: "0"
 2: "1"
 3: "LPAY"
 4: "F635P3B"
 5: "LPAY00001"
 6: "FRM"
 7: "HOUSTON GROUP (aka CORPORATE ADVOCATES INC.) THE"
 8: ""
 9: ""
 10: ""
 11: "Sacramento"
 12: "CA"
 13: "95814-2825"
 14: "(916) 447-9884"
 15: ""
 16: "6499.98"
 17: "17.19"
 18: "0"
 19: ""
 20: "6517.17"
 21: "39309.23"
 22: "N"
 23: ""
 24: ""
 "5: "
 $
```

See slight glitch at last line above.

```
 $ col < testData.txt | ./testSplit 
 0: "677710"
 1: "0"
 2: "1"
 3: "LPAY"
 4: "F635P3B LPAY00001"
 5: "FRM"
 6: "HOUSTON GROUP (aka CORPORATE ADVOCATES INC.) THE"
 7: ""
 8: ""
 9: ""
 10: "Sacramento"
 11: "CA"
 12: "95814-2825"
 13: "(916) 447-9884"
 14: ""
 15: "6499.98 17.19"
 16: "0"
 17: ""
 18: "6517.17 39309.23"
 19: "N"
 $
```

What the heck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, it's `col` that's ignoring the tabs (it's converting some of them to spaces):

```
$ diff -u <(od -c testData.txt) <(col <testData.txt | od -c)
--- /dev/fd/63  2013-11-10 00:06:29.532490383 -0600
+++ /dev/fd/62  2013-11-10 00:06:29.532490383 -0600
@@ -1,12 +1,12 @@
 0000000   6   7   7   7   1   0  \t   0  \t   1  \t   L   P   A   Y  \t
-0000020   F   6   3   5   P   3   B  \t   L   P   A   Y   0   0   0   0
+0000020   F   6   3   5   P   3   B       L   P   A   Y   0   0   0   0
 0000040   1  \t   F   R   M  \t   H   O   U   S   T   O   N       G   R
 0000060   O   U   P       (   a   k   a       C   O   R   P   O   R   A
 0000100   T   E       A   D   V   O   C   A   T   E   S       I   N   C
 0000120   .   )       T   H   E  \t  \t  \t  \t   S   a   c   r   a   m
 0000140   e   n   t   o  \t   C   A  \t   9   5   8   1   4   -   2   8
 0000160   2   5  \t   (   9   1   6   )       4   4   7   -   9   8   8
-0000200   4  \t  \t   6   4   9   9   .   9   8  \t   1   7   .   1   9
+0000200   4  \t  \t   6   4   9   9   .   9   8       1   7   .   1   9
-0000220  \t   0  \t  \t   6   5   1   7   .   1   7  \t   3   9   3   0
+0000220  \t   0  \t  \t   6   5   1   7   .   1   7       3   9   3   0
-0000240   9   .   2   3  \t   N  \t  \t  \t  \r  \n
+0000240   9   .   2   3  \t   N  \n
-0000253
+0000247
```

To fix your actual problem, you need to remove the `\r` character.  `chomp` doesn't do that.  For field 25, you're essentially doing `print qq{25: "\r"\n}`.  The `\r` moves the cursor back to the left margin, causing the `"` to overwrite the `2`.

Here's a cleaned up version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

binmode STDIN, ':crlf';

my $line = <STDIN>;
chomp($line);
my @p = split /\t/, $line, -1;
for my $idx (0 .. $#p) { print $idx.": \"".$p[$idx]."\"\n"; }
exit(0);
```

Major changes:

1. `binmode STDIN, ':crlf'` turns on CRLF->LF translation when reading.  This gets rid of the `\r`.
2. Chomp the line, not the individual parts.  This isn't fatal, because `chomp` only removes the line-ending character, but it's a waste of time to chomp all the elements of `@p` when what you really wanted was `chomp $line`.
3. Adding -1 to `split`.  This keeps the empty fields at the end.  Otherwise, the output would stop with field 22.  (The empty fields used to be displayed because the trailing `\r` meant the last one wasn't empty.)
4. Changing the `for` loop to use `0 .. $#p` isn't necessary; it's just simpler.
5. Using `strict` and `warnings` is always a good idea.  This required inserting a number of `my` statements.

Comment: The binmode statement did not remove the '\r'. But I can do that manually. Spot on with everything else. Much thanx!